# Scrapy crawl pages but doesn't scraped items

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

Here is my spider

```
from scrapy import Selector
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

from Diplom.items import QuestionItem


class ConsultSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "consultation"
    allowed_domains = ['health.mail.ru']
    start_urls = ['https://health.mail.ru/consultation/1579497']

    rules = {
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('.*\/consultation\/\d+'),), callback="parse_item", follow=True),

     }

    def parse_item(self, response):
        items = []
        root = Selector(response)
        posts = root.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]')
        for post in posts:
            item = QuestionItem()
            item['question'] = post.xpath(
            '//div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]').extract()
            item['answer'] = post.xpath('//div[3]/div[2]/div[2]').extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

The problem is that spider enter to links as described in rule

> INFO: Crawled 8 pages (at 8 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)

but this doesn't return any items. My code works if I change the class and  write like this

```
class ConsultSpider(scrapy.Spider):
....
```

but this is not working with `Rule`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scrapy.Spider is the simplest spider that would, basically, visit the URLs defined in start_urls or returned by start_requests().

CrawlSpider when you need a "crawling" behavior - extracting the links and following them:

This is the most commonly used spider for crawling regular websites, as   it provides a convenient mechanism for following links by defining a set of rules. It may not be the best suited for your particular web sites or project, but it’s generic enough for several cases, so you can start from it and override it as needed for more custom functionality, or just implement your own spider.

By this "scrapy.spider" don't follow rules and "crawlspider" is the one that follows rules ,Thus the  problem is not with those two  So please check your xpath selector.

Comment: Thank you for good information, also you advice helped me. Problem was in xpath.